# How to make my WearOS app work on LockScreen?

Tags: android, wear-os, lockscreen, lockscreenwidget

How do I make my WearOS app work on LockScreen? My app reacts to tapping the smartwatch on an NFC tag. I hear about widget, but it's almost dead now. Is lockscreen programming still possible in Android app development? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets

> Only Android versions lower than 5.0 support lock-screen widgets.

So lock-screen widgets have been unavailable for quite some time now.